# Spring RestTemplate response body is null when trying to parse JSON

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I've been trying many solutions from similar solved problems in this page but I can't make it work. I'm making a get petition to obtain an array JSON, and I want to map those values into my class.

I got this class:

```
public class Devices {

    private String DeviceName;
    private String DeviceDescription;

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return DeviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.DeviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getDeviceDescription() {
        return DeviceDescription;
    }

    public void setDeviceDescription(String deviceDescription) {
        this.DeviceDescription = deviceDescription;
    }

}
```

The GET petition returns this JSON below:

```
[{"DeviceName":"AMIXT-20EC-VIDM0000","DeviceDescription":"Samsung device "},{"DeviceName":"AMIXT-E0F9-VIDM0001","DeviceDescription":"Tablet Huawei"}]
```

I've tried solutions like this one (also tried with getForObject):

```
ResponseEntity<Devices[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Devices[].class);
```

As we can see [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl16S.png), the body properties are null

What am I missing?

Comment: You should follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). It will prevent you from many similar problems since various mapping libraries expect your POJOs to be correctly declared and named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the name of the fields in the `JSON`, name start with an upper-case letter.

One simple solution would be to use `@JsonProperty` annotation on the variables defined in the `Devices` class

```java
public class Devices {

    @JsonProperty("DeviceName")
    private String deviceName;

    @JsonProperty("DeviceDescription")
    private String deviceDescription;

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getDeviceDescription() {
        return deviceDescription;
    }

    public void setDeviceDescription(String deviceDescription) {
        this.deviceDescription = deviceDescription;
    }
}
```